# Затруднения с запятой

Tags: запятые

"Давайте(,) кто выше?"

Речь идёт о качелях. Назрела мысль, что тут может быть запятая. Так ли это?
Спасибо заранее за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

***Давайте, кто выше.***

Это неполное предложение. Полный вариант может выглядеть так: Давайте соревноваться (давайте посмотрим), кто раскачается выше.

Сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед союзным словом КТО.

Примеры:

https://picsis.ru/delfiny/4527-a-davaite-kto-vyshe.html

https://ok.ru/exwoman/topic/67396788612009

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (о шахматах)

Для сравнения:

***Давай сыграем в шахматы. Давайте споем.***

Это аналитическфя форма глагола, сложное будущее время, образуется сочетанием частиц ДАВАЙ (ТЕ), ДАЙ (ДАЙТЕ) с глаголами 1 лица. В предложении является **простым глагольным сказуемым.**

Запятая после частицы не ставится.

Comment: Частица "давай" не обязательно должна сочетаться с глаголом первого лица. Вот другие примеры из Кузнецова: "давай бог ноги", "давай все по домам". Подозреваю, что допустимы оба варианта: с запятой и без. Примеров без запятой в книгах не так уж мало, чтобы списать их все на ошибки (я искал выражения типа "давай кто быстрее/выше/дальше/глубже/т.п.").

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что нет запятой. Сравните: *Давай сыграем в шахматы. Давайте споем.*